# Writing code to codes.db incorrectly

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to make a random code generator in python that writes to a database.  I have the codes generating and writing to the database, but instead of adding full codes to the database it loops through letters.  Here is my code for the code generator:

```
import string
import random
import sqlite3
def id_generator():
    db = sqlite3.connect('codes.db')
    c = db.cursor()
    number_of_codes = 10
    stringLength = 9
    id_code = input("what letter should this begin with: \n")
    id_code = id_code.upper()
    dict_ofcodes = []
    for x in range(0, number_of_codes):
        codez = (''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for i in range(stringLength)))
        final_codez = (id_code + codez)
        dict_ofcodes.insert(x, final_codez)
    print (dict_ofcodes)
    dict_ofcodes_tuple = tuple(dict_ofcodes)
    print(dict_ofcodes_tuple)
    for x in range(0, number_of_codes):
        c.executemany(''' INSERT INTO codes(codes) VALUES(?)''', dict_ofcodes_tuple[x])
    db.commit()
    db.close()
id_generator()
```

Here is what it prints

```
['AALRRIULNC', 'AZTKZBKTLK', 'ATWMWYWICO', 'AWQJIJYEJH', 'AQFIONPUNJ', 'AMJRXUIJXM', 'AUDRLSBLSG', 'ABXYXDUMPD', 'AUAXRQURBH', 'ADQEVIRDFU']
('AALRRIULNC', 'AZTKZBKTLK', 'ATWMWYWICO', 'AWQJIJYEJH', 'AQFIONPUNJ', 'AMJRXUIJXM', 'AUDRLSBLSG', 'ABXYXDUMPD', 'AUAXRQURBH', 'ADQEVIRDFU')
```

It writes to the database single letters of the codes:
    A
    F
    Y
and so on

The code I used to create the schema is contained in the a python file

```
    import sqlite3

    def writeDB():
        db = sqlite3.connect('codes.db')
        c = db.cursor()

    # Create table
        c.execute('''CREATE TABLE codes (codes TEXT)''')


    # Save (commit) the changes
        db.commit()

    #can also close the connection if done with it.
    # be sure any changes have been committed or they will be lost.
        db.close()
writeDB()
```

I created the file with the mac terminal.
  How could I write the full codes to the database?

Comment: Please show the SQL statement you used to create the `codes` table.

Comment: The Code I used to create the table is CREATE TABLE codes (codes TEXT);

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line:

> ```
> c.executemany(''' INSERT INTO codes(codes) VALUES(?)''', dict_ofcodes_tuple[x])
> ```

`executemany` is used to iterate over a list of parameters and call the sql statement for each parameter. So your dict_ofcodes_tupel[x] is treated as a character array and the INSERT is called for each character.

If you want to insert the entire string as one, use execute() instead.

> ```
> c.execute(''' INSERT INTO codes(codes) VALUES(?)''', (dict_ofcodes_tuple[x],))
> ```

or

> ```
> c.execute(''' INSERT INTO codes(codes) VALUES(?)''', [dict_ofcodes_tuple[x]])
> ```